# Problems selecting all rows

Tags: java, sql-server, select, jdbc, org.json

I have 558 rows in a SQL Server table.
If I write `"SELECT * FROM table"` I get empty resultset.
But, If I write `"SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table"` I get a resultset with 100 rows.
Sometimes TOP `600` works, sometimes only TOP `200`, really strange, like some memory issues...
I have closed rs/ps/conn in code.

Jboss 7.1.3, Java 1.7, tried with both of these drivers `(net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver, com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 4.1)`.

Nothing in error-log (bot Jboss and SQL Server).

Code:

```
<%

@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<% response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8"); %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.*" %>
<%
    String table = "tblTable";

    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    int amount = 10;
    int start = 0;
    int echo = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int total = 0;

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbTables", "sa", "sa");

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT count(*) As num FROM "+table;
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            total = rs.getInt("num");
        }
    } catch(Exception e){

    }

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT TOP 500 * FROM "+table;

        Statement ps = conn.createStatement();
        //ps.setFetchSize(200);
        //int fetchSize = ps.getFetchSize();
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
            ja.put(rs.getString("colOne"));
            ja.put(rs.getString("colTwo"));
            array.put(ja);
        }
    rs.close();
    ps.close();

        //out.print(fetchSize);

        result.put("draw", "1");
        result.put("recordsTotal", total);
        result.put("recordsFiltered", total);
        result.put("data", array);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");

        out.print(result.toString(4));

    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
    conn.close();
    }
%>
```

Comment: Could you please show some piece of code.

Comment: Here. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Be very careful here. Your sql is quickly approaching sql injection territory.

Comment: This is faaar from production. It's just a simple test-code, which doesn't work well :)

Comment: Is your database object fully qualified?  DBName.Schema.Object?

Comment: I tried adding full name to table string ([dbName].[dbo].[tblName]), but the same problem.

Comment: I even tried with ps.setFetchSize(1000) but with no luck

Comment: I'd set up a trace with SQL Profiler and see what code is being executed against sql and the rowcount affected.

Comment: I would suggest rather than using * you mention the specific column name in the query "SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM table"  This will give you all the rows.  I may be wrong but with sql server jdbc driver you cannot get results using <select *>.

Comment: You are ignoring/swallowing the exceptions that are - potentially - thrown. At minimum print them out (`e.printStacktrace()`) or log them. Add logging and post any exceptions you might get.

Comment: no logs with e.printStackTrace();

Comment: tried with "SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM table", but with no luck.

Comment: Tracing with SQL Profiler all I can see is that "exec sp_unprepare 1" is executed after those two select statements in my code. I removed first Select, but still my second "Select" results as empty. After "exec sp_unprepare 1" there is SQL_BatchStarting and SQL:BatchCompleted containing complet Select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :)

The problem was not in SQL... It is in JSONArray :)
Apparently it has some issues.

In "While" I added our.print(rs.getString("COL1")); and I got the ALL printed out.

I'm using org.json-20120521.jar library.
Could anyone recommend something else? Or even better, is there a workaround on how to fix this so I don't have to change library and code in other files...?

Comment: Solved JSON library issue. If values in db table is NULL then this library doesn't handle it very well. I got NullPointerException (had to remove try-catch which didn't catch the exception?!?). So, for now, I'm fetching values with total = rs.getInt("num")+""; > forcing empty string to fetched values...